# Kotlin equals on custom generic class

Tags: kotlin, generics, equals

I can't seem to figure out how to write equals function for a custom generic collection.
The class contains a generic `data: Array<T>` as a field

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    if (this === other) return true
    if (other == null || this::class != other::class) return false

    other as CustomCollection<*>

    if (size != other.size) return false

    return (0 until size).all { data[it] == other.data[it] }
}
```

This fails with the following error: `Unsupported Array Nothing in return type is illegal`

But the language does not give me any alternative.
If I cast my object to `CustomCollection<Any>` I get a warning, which is annoying.
Is there a way to properly treat this case without warnings or errors?

Comment: Can you share the rest of your class. I'm not seeing any problems with your code. https://pl.kotl.in/tG4FCIR5p

Answer (score 0):

If you check

```
// not this
if (other == null || this::class != other::class) return false
//but:
if (other == null || other !is CustomCollection<*>) return false
```

```
class CustomCollection<T>(private val data: Array<T>) {
    val size
        get() = data.size
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || other !is CustomCollection<*>) return false

        if (size != other.size) return false

        /* this will return true if [other] has a longer array that has the same 
         * start, not sure if you want that, consider         
         */
        // return data.contentEquals(other.data)
        return (0 until size).all { data[it] == other.data[it] }
    }   
}
```

doesn't give me any warnings

Comment: You example gives me exactly the following error in IntelliJ Idea:
Unsupported [Array<Nothing> in return type is illegal].  

This is a compiler error at the last line when accessing `data` field.
The code cannot be compiled and such cannot even run.
There is no more code in the class that affects this issue.
I tried just your example.